# Having multiple fragments at one screen with Jetpack Navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

[Two fragments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbnFi.png)

I'm using navigation component and trying to understand is it possible to have two or more opened fragments simultaneously like mail app (one fragment is a list of mails, another fragment is detailed mail view). It's desirable to have them inside another container parent fragment.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's even recommended to design your app for [multiple screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes). You can do so by creating [alternative layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts), e.g:

```
res/layout/fragment_items.xml          # Screens smaller than 600dp available width
res/layout-w600dp/fragment_items.xml   # Screens 600dp wide and bigger
```

where `layout-w600dp/fragment_items.xml` [includes both fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating#AddInLayout). This way you keep the same navigation destination and don't need to complicate things with [conditional navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional).

> It's desirable to have them inside another container parent fragment.

Depends. If you are going to use your list-fragment on multiple places, yes, because it would reduce duplicate code. If not, or your list-fragment is going to be different on multiple screens (you might add or hide some buttons) you don't need the container; and can just modify the `fragment_items.xml` layout for different screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer:) But as far as I know, navigation destination is a fragment, but in this case, I need to go to the screen that has 2 fragments. How navigation to this layout will be look like?

Comment: Either navigate to your list-fragment (with the detail-fragment in it's layout depending on screen size) or navigate to the container fragment you put both in. Navigation will always be something like `findNavController().navigate()` with the action or destination id or a NavDirection (requires the safeargs dependency) argument, see: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate

Comment: was the question really about screen sizes or managing multiple fragments at once in screen?